# Call current position in onEachFeature leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, php

How can I call my current location inside `onEachFeature` in Leaflet.
It's working outside but I just want to call it inside `L.Controler.Layers`.

```
var cauayan = L.geoJSON(cauayan, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
        function getPosition(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

            if (marker) {
                map.removeLayer(marker);
            }
            if (circle) {
                map.removeLayer(circle);
            }
            marker = L.marker([lat, long]);
            circle = L.circle([lat, long], {
                radius: accuracy,
            });

            var featureGroup = L.featureGroup([marker, circle]).addTo(map);

            map.fitBounds(featureGroup.getBounds());

            var cauayan = L.Routing.control({
                waypoints: [
                    L.latLng(lat, long),
                    L.latLng(16.937663, 121.764436),
                ],
            });
        }
    },
    style: {
        fillColor: "red",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        color: "green",
    },
});
```

There is no error in my code, not even in map because it should be white screen. But if I run, the only code working in inside of this is the style. I will put it inside control layers because I will make a specific location to be tracked by current location.

Comment: From your question and code it's not clear what you are trying to do with your app. Please edit your question and describe desired behavior/functionality of your map.

Comment: O I'm sorry, I'm new here. I have a project where I can see my routes in specific college universities using leaflet. I have a L.Controler.layer where I should turn on and off that location and the live routes at the same time using the controler layer through onEachFeature. But this code is not working inside onEachFeature but I only get my current location outside the onEachFeature. I should have 5 different university. But since that code is not working, I can only use 1 university to track my current location to that university. https://programs.epizy.com/maps/index.html check here.

Comment: Please don't put additional explanations in comments, but rather [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/441437/edit) your question and put them there. Also explain what you mean by " I should turn on and off that location and the live routes at the same time using the controler layer through onEachFeature." What is "that location"? What are "live routes"?